# Authorization Code grant generates 405 in WSO2 APIM

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to implement OAuth2 Authorization Code flow with WSO2 APIM 2.6 but I get a 405 method not allowed. Here is what I did

1. Intall WSO2 APIM (no WOS2 IS nor IS-KM is in my environment. only APIM is present)
2. Create a spring boot REST service with `@Restcontroller`. This leads to base path as `http://localhost:8080`
3. Create an API in API publisher. This point to the REST service
4. As admin create an application in API store and subscribe to the API. The call back URL is simply `http://localhost:8080` as shown in the image below
   [image]
5. Call the authorize method of WSO2 APIM with the following URL

> https://localhost:9443/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080&client_id=EaTfmmwQT4fWciN4WnU1YyyYYYsa

When I call this URL, I'm redirected to the login page of WSO2 APIM like below

[image]

I just log in with admin/admin

6. Upon login, I though I'd be redirected to a authorize page, but instead I'm redirected to the following error page

[image]

Coul you guyz help me here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying with https://localhost:9443/authorize which is wrong. That is why it is redirecting to the carbon console. You can use one of the following URLs.

1. https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize
2. https://localhost:8243/authorize

This will prompt you to a different login page where you can use your login credentials.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Authorization+Code+Grant

Comment: Awesome mate. I was reading an old documentation. Do think I can make a doudle redirect ? Like one redirect to the client with the code and another to the user-agent without the code so that the code is never sent to the user agent ?